# raw partition as mounted vmdk not detected by windows installer in virtualbox

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

(Arch newbie here) I am running Arch 4.10, and would like to install Windows 10 in a virtual machine, but on a separate partition.

**Background:**

My drive layout (GPT Partition schema):

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2097151    2095104  1023M EFI System
/dev/sda2     4194304 1052770303 1048576000   500G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  1052770304 1743810559  691040256 329.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  1743810560 1953523711  209713152   100G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda5     2097152    4194303    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
```

Partition functions:

- `sda1` efi disk info
- `sda3` arch home/opt data
- `sda4` arch system

`sda2` - Windows partition to be installed in virtualbox

I create a vmdk using:

```
sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "/opt/win_part.vmdk" -rawdisk /dev/sda2
```

followed by setting permissions and owner:

```
sudo chmod a+rwx /opt/win_part.vmdk && sudo chown user /opt/win_part.vmdk
```

Setting up the Virtual Machine by adding the:

- vmdk of the harddrive partition : `win_part.vmdk`
- Windows ISO
- any additional settings.

Also installing the [virtualbox-extras](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/virtualbox-ext-oracle/) for USB3 support, etc.

**Problem:**

I proceed by booting the `Windows 10 iso` in Virtualbox done like one would normally install Windows with a USB or DVD.

The issue comes when trying to install Windows to the hard drive, it is not detected by the Windows installer as seen below.

[image]

Then looking at if the hard drive is actually detected by the system:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The issue comes when trying to install Windows to the hard drive, it
>   is not detected by the Windows installer as seen below.

This is because your VM's firmware is currently set to BIOS instead of EFI.  Windows cannot be installed on a GPT disk if legacy mode/compatability mode is enabled.  Linux doesn't have the same limitations.

In order to resolve this problem you should run the following command.

> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware efi

You can use the following command to revert back

> VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --firmware bios

While [3.13. Alternative firmware (EFI)](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#efi) indicate Windows support for VirtualBox's EFI implementation [Changeset 66268 in vbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/changeset/66268/vbox) says otherwise.  [UEFI support for Windows guests](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7702) also confirms that fact.

> Note that the VirtualBox EFI support is experimental and will be
>   enhanced as EFI matures and becomes more widespread. Mac OS X, Linux
>   and newer Windows guests are known to work fine. Windows 7 guests are
>   unable to boot with the VirtualBox EFI implementation.

Comment: There might be additional changes you have to make to your Linux installation.  Since the question is not about your Linux installation, I focused my answer, on the reason your unable to install Windows on the virtual hdd in question.

Comment: well hi again @Ramhound, thanks, I shall try that - in reference to my previous post about the uefi bios, I wanted to use an actual partition to install my Windows on (on my Desktop)

Comment: @Cybex - I know nothing about your "other" question for the purposes of this question.  If I had not specifically looked at your past questions I wouldn't have put the two questions together.

Comment: I get the same issue on an older MBR laptop. I have installed arch onto it, created a vmdk of a raw partition, given myself access to the /dev/sdXY and set permissions to 766 on the vmdk, yet Windows installer does not detect the hard drive